# XSLT Transformation Using msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"

Tags: php, xslt, transformation, msxsl

I have an XSLT stylesheet with the following header

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
    xmlns:redirect="org.apache.xalan.xslt.extensions.Redirect"
    extension-element-prefixes="redirect"
   xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:my-ext="ext1">
```

I have also have custom functions:

```
<msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="my-ext">

    var lineCounter = 0;
    var totalPages = 0;
    var currentPage = 1;
    var currentObject = '';
    var colSpan = 0;

    function getLineCounter()
    {
        return lineCounter;
    }

    function updateLineCounter(aValue)
    {
        lineCounter += aValue;
         return '';
    }
```

My custom functions are used throughout my xsl.  When I transform my XML using this XSL from a command line, using **msxsl.exe** it works perfectly and produces perfect HTML.

OK, here's my issue: I'm trying to use PHP to perform the transformation on the server and send back results.  I have used this procedure many times before without issue; howver, this is the first time I've tried it with MSXSL extensions and functions.

Sample errors look like:

```
Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [xsltprocessor.transformtoxml]: xmlXPathCompOpEval: **function resetAll not found** in D:\Development\AppServ\www\RJFWEB\jqueryFileTree\PHPMain.php on line 49

Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [xsltprocessor.transformtoxml]: **Unregistered function** in D:\Development\AppServ\www\RJFWEB\jqueryFileTree\PHPMain.php on line 49
```

We can see that functions are not found/understood - although this is the same code I run at command line using **msXSL.exe.**

SO, ultimately I'm trying to find out if there's something I need to fix/add in my PHP.ini to understand how to use the MS extensions OR do I need to change the XSL stylesheets?

Man... I hope this question makes sense!  Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Rob

My phpInfo displays

```
**XSL**
XSL                                      enabled
libxslt Version                              1.1.23
libxslt compiled against libxml Version      2.6.32
EXSLT                                    enabled
libexslt Version                             0.8.13
```

Answer (score 1):

The `msxsl:script` is a proprietary extension allowing you to write extension functions with JScript or VBScript, I don't think libxslt supports that. With PHP 5 and libxslt you can however write extension functions in PHP, see http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php. So that seems to be the way to go, if you can't use pure XSLT to implement your requirements, then you need to port the functions written in J(ava)Script to PHP and make use of http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php to use those functions in XSLT.

As an alternative, in case you run PHP on Windows where you have MSXML available, you might want to try to use it from PHP, it should be possible with the help of http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php e.g. `new COM("MSXML2.DomDocument.3.0")` for instance should give you an MSXML DOM document with a `transformNode` method to run your stylesheet using `msxsl:script`.

Comment: Martin, thanks for the info.  Unfortunately, my situation is not as clear cut.  My existing XSL (12 stylesheets) (w/Javascript extensions) is already a production-ready batch system.  I wanted to reuse this code in a front-end manner using PHP/HTML.  In brief, I need to extract nodes from a large set of XML files and produce "single" pieces of HTML output based on a user's search criteria.  Re-implementing in PHP is not feasible for me.  Thanks again for your input. Rob+